# how can i getText() From edittext programmatically created

Tags: android, android-edittext

i create two edittext programmatically and i need to get text from him
this is my code for create edittext

```
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

//First EditText
edText = new EditText(getActivity());
edText.setId(0);  
edText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      1f));

edText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext);
edText.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

linear=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittextpanel);
linear.addView(edText ,layoutParams);

nb++;

//Second EditText           
edText = new EditText(getActivity());
edText.setId(1);  
edText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                  1f));

edText.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
edText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext);       
linear.addView(edText ,layoutParams);
```

Help please i'm blocked

Answer (score 4):

```
edText = new EditText(getActivity());

edText.setId(id);

String stringAnswer = edText.getText().toString();
```

If you want to create and reference more than one edit text you'll have to create an EditText array

```
List<EditText> allEDs = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

Then create the Edit Texts

```
edText = new EditText(getActivity());

edText.setId(id);
```

Push them into the array

```
allEDs.add(edText);
```

Create a string array same size as the EditText array

```
String[] ETResults = new String[allEDs.size()];
```

Loop through the EditText array and put converted results into String array

```
for(int i=0; i < allEDs.size(); i++){
        ETResults[i] = allEDs.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

And then assign the desired string to whatever you want

```
String stringAnswer = ETResults[i];
```

Comment: This won't work when using `edText` to instantiate both `EditText` widgets as `edText` will always be referencing the last (i.e., second) `EditText` which was instantiated.

Comment: Updated the answer to incorporate multiple edittexts.

Comment: You do realise that all of the code relating to `ArrayList`, `String[]` and `for` loop can be reduced to one or two lines when retrieving the text don't you?

Comment: You do realize that people benefit from well explained and commented code, don't you? The objective here isn't to optimize since the person asking is obviously still learning the basics.

Comment: Yes but your first code block would only work for the second `EditText` and the code you added is far too complicated for just 2 `EditTexts`. Not only that but it's overcomplicated anyway. Assuming consecutive ids for the `EditTexts` you can get the text using `String text = ((EditText)linear.findViewById(id)).getText().toString()`;. No need to complicate things with an `ArrayList` or reading every `String` from every `EditText` into a `String[]` - if you know the id just use `findViewById`

Comment: It'll become quite convoluted and impractical if you have more than a few elements. Better is to store the EditTexts in an array so that you can later reference that array in order to get whatever information you want, as opposed to trying to figure out in which ID range the Edittexts are placed in.

Comment: But think about your code. To use `String stringAnswer = ETResults[i];` means you have decided on what `i` is. The elements of `ETResults` are populated by the text from `allEDs` `ArrayList` where each of index of `ETResults` corresponds to the index of `allEDs`. Finally each index of `allEDs` corresponds to the resource id set for each `EditText`. If you know what `i` needs to be you can find it from the `LinearLayout` using `findViewById`. A `LinearLayout` is a `ViewGroup` and maintains its own 'array' of child views.

Comment: Your method entails knowing the id of the view you want to reference. When you're creating multiple elements, that information becomes less and less tangible, necessitating that you go through the code to see which IDs' you've set to which elements. Much frowns. Instead of the hassle of doing that you can reference everything in arrays and then just use the appropriate array whenever you want to extract information.

Comment: Your method relies on knowing the position in the array(s) of the view you want to reference. What's the difference? The position *IS* (or could be) the same as the id. Besides, the OP only want's an answer for two `EditTexts`. My answer addresses this directly - your's adds unnecessary complications for very many views. Also, if I personally wanted multiple views (`TextViews`, `EditTexts`, whatever) I'd use a `ListView` which would handle everything for me.

Comment: Thanks! this helped

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) context.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        for(int i = 0; i <viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
            if(viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
                EditText view = (EditText)viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                Log.i("val " , " val " + ((EditText) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).getText() + "  view  "+ view.getText() );
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Error in Bind layout", ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a reference to both `EditTexts`. Put the following in the main body of your `Fragment` to make them globally accessible..

```
EditText edText1;
EditText edText2;
```

Then in the method you've shown you can use...

```
// Do some stuff

edText1 = new EditText(getActivity());

// Do some more stuff

edText2 = new EditText(getActivity());

...
```

Later when you need to get the text you can use...

```
String text1 = edText1.getText().toString();
String text2 = edText2.getText().toString();
```

Alternatively you can find them later in your `Fragment` using their ids...

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.edittextpanel);
EditText et = (EditText) linear.findViewById(0);
String text1 = et.getText().toString();
et = (EditText) linear.findViewById(1);
String text2 = et.getText().toString();
```